# Loop through xunit unit test method params for memberdata

Tags: c#, xunit

I have this method to test using xUnit

```
public class Cal
{       
        public int Output { get; set; }    

        public void Add(int num1, int num2) => Output = num1 + num2;
}
```

and in my unit test xUnit, I have

```
public class CalTest
{
        private readonly Cal _cal;

        public CalTest()
        {
            _cal = new Cal();
        }

        [Theory, MemberData(nameof(Data))] // Arrange
        public void CanAdd2Numbers(int expected, params int[] valuesToAdd)
        {
            // Act
            foreach (var value in valuesToAdd)
            {
                //_cal.Add(value[0], value[1]);
            }

            // Assert
            Assert.Equal(expected, _cal.Output);
        }

        public static IEnumerable<object[]> Data()
        {
            return new List<object[]>
            {
                new object[] { 1, 2, 3 },
                new object[] { -1, 1, 0 }
            };
        }
 }
```

How do I pass the first element of the array as `num1`, second element as `num2` and third element as expected result ? and I do not want to use `InlineData`.

Comment: If I understand what you mean... You can't statically, however you could create a dedicated test that does this, more or less

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can assign MemberData array elements to test method arguments like this:

```
public class Test
{
    [Theory]
    [MemberData(nameof(Data))]
    public void CanAdd2Numbers(int num1, int num2, int expected)
    {
        var actual = num1 + num2;
        Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<object[]> Data()
    {
        return new List<object[]>
        {
            new object[] { 1, 2, 3 },
            new object[] { -1, 1, 0 }
        };
    }
}
```

You also might like this blog post to get an idea on how to convert your TestData to be strongly typed: https://andrewlock.net/creating-strongly-typed-xunit-theory-test-data-with-theorydata/

Answer (score 1):

You can use tuple:

```
   public static IEnumerable<(int a, int b,int c)> Data()
    {
        return new List<(int a, int b,int c)>
        {
            (a:1,b:2,c:3),
            (a:1,b:-1,c:0)
        };
    }
```

and then you will use it like this

```
        _cal.Add(value.a, value.b);
        Assert.Equal(value.c, _cal.Output);
```

Comment: How my `[Theory, MemberData(nameof(Data3))]` would be?